# Template function

Tags: c++, templates

Can anyone describe the following declaration?

```
template<> float func<float>(char *txt)
{
blah blah 
}
```

What is the second <> for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `template<>` means that this function is a template specialization. The second `<float>` means that this is the specialization for `float`.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> void somefunc(T arg) {
    std::cout << "Normal template called\n";
}

template<> void somefunc<float>(float arg) {
    std::cout << "Template specialization called\n";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    somefunc(1); // prints out "Normal template called"
    somefunc(1.0f); // prints out "Template specialization called"

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a specialized template function. It happens when you try to specialized a generic template function.
Usually you will have another deceleration as

```
template<typename T> float func(char *txt) {
    T vars[1024];
    blah blah
}
```

It happens sometime you want to do a specialized declaration for certain type T. In previous example, if T is bool type, you might want to change the behavior of vars array to save some space (because each bool entry might still take 32bits).

```
template<> float func<bool>(char *txt) {
    int vars[32];
    blah blah
}
```

By defining a specialized version, you are allowed to manipulate the vars array in bit-wise
manner.